# Looping block device

Tags: partitioning, usb, mount

I'm running Ubuntu 14.04 and I was creating a USB with centOS 7.
I ran `sudo dd if=/home/user/Downloads/CentOS-7-x86_64-Everything-1511.iso of=/dev/sde1` instead of `of=/dev/sde` and now I'm seeing an unremovable  Block Device in my disks manager that point to what I think is an extracted iso in my Filesystem root path.
When I try to remove it or format it I get this error

> Error unmounting /dev/dm-0: Command-line `umount  "/dev/dm-0"' exited with non-zero exit status 1: umount: /: device is busy.
>           (In some cases useful info about processes that use
>            the device is found by lsof(8) or fuser(1))
>    (udisks-error-quark, 14)

How can I remove this?
Everytime I plug the USB where the iso was copied to (even if it's formatted now) it starts loading a copy of the image and mounting it.

i managed to reduce those to 2. One is under

> /dev/ubuntu-vg/swap_1

and is not mounted

the other under

> /dev/ubuntu-vg/root

and It print me the error.

Comment: Is there a safe way to remove this, please?